# Loading configuration async in JavaScript, how best to wait for response?

Tags: javascript

This is what I am trying to do:

- Request a JSON object from remote server script
- WAIT until the JavaScripts gets all the response data
- print a value from the response object

I'm trying to use setTimeout in the get config function to recall itself after 1 second if the value is undefined, when it's no longer undefined do something with the value.

Alternatively it seems I could just create some method that loops for some number of seconds, but i'd like to avoid that if there is a better way to accomplish what i'm trying to do? My current code just seems to recurse without any delay which breaks my runtime

Thanks for any ideas, heres the code:

```
function runApplication() {
    var initialiser = new Initialiser();
    var config = new Config();
    initialiser.fetchConfigurations(config);
    config.alertValue('setting1');
}

function Initialiser() {
    debug.log("Started");
}

Initialiser.prototype.fetchConfigurations = function(config) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = CONFIGURATION_SERVER_URL;
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            var configObject = eval('(' + req.responseText + ')');
            config.setConfig(configObject);
        } else {
            debug.log("Downloading config data...please wait...");
        }
    }
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send(null);
}
function Config() {
    this.config
}

Config.prototype.setConfig = function(configObject) {
    this.config = configObject;
}

Config.prototype.getValue = function(setting) {
    if(this.config === undefined) {
        setTimeout(this.getValue(setting), 1000);   
    } else {
        return this.config[setting];
    }
}


Config.prototype.alertValue = function(setting) {
    if(this.config === undefined) {
        setTimeout(this.alertValue(setting), 1000); 
    } else {
        alert(this.config[setting]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Make a callback so that in `setConfig` not only the object property is assigned, but also the value is alerted/printed in the page/whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm looking at, you should just add an extra step to `.setConfig`, which handles the next piece.

```
Config.prototype.setConfig = function (data) {
    this.config = data;
    this.doSomethingAfterTheDataExists();
};
```

There are lots of ways to do this...
...writing a moderator/observer/pub-sub implementation is dirt-simple, and could be done in relatively few lines for the benefit given...

Writing a Promise system would be even more powerful, but would require more work (because it's like the above implementations, with an added layer of abstraction, to make a really clean and straightforward interface for async).

The other alternative to having `.setConfig` publish a message, or fire another method, would be to call another method, after `.setConfig` in the AJAX call.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    // .......
    config.setConfig(/* ... */);
    config.doSomethingAfterTheDataExists();
};
```

If you're making multiple AJAX calls, with multiple assignments to multiple properties, and you want to wait until every single call is done, then you really should look into implementing a Promise system.
It will save your sanity and would be well-worth the ~60-100 lines which you could minify into oblivion.

If you're just waiting for that one response to come back, then keep in mind, what happens after the `onreadystatechange` says that it's finished and the data's there (your success check) is synchronous.
The waiting is the async part.
Once it's delivered, everything (including the stuff inside of that check), goes back to being procedural.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) and [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) **with success/done** callback.

Comment: I'd love to have that option, however I can't use jQuery or other large external libraries. The app runs on an embedded browser with very limited memory. Need to stick with plain JS

Answer (score 0):

You could use a synchronous call instead of asynchronous call for XMLHttpRequest.  But this may not be the *best* option if your your users need to interact with the web page while you wait for a response.

```
...
req.open("GET", url, false);
request.send(null);
```